# How can I Change Primary Menu block to certain pages using PHP?

Tags: theming

I have navigation menu as follow, no 1. is main navigation and no 2. is sub menu of Cooking Menu.
[image]

I want Change navigation menu at Cooking Page as follow. 
[image] 
I want to get sub menus of cooking menu into main navigation and remove Cooking. how can I achieve this ? because i'm new to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I can think into two alternative ways to do that, maybe it helps:

**With CSS:** Adding those submenu links duplicated in the main level (1) and hiding / showing them depending on the page. Something like:

```
Home        --> Normal
Find store  --> Normal
Cooking     --> (Visible by default, hidden in cooking page)
  |_Recipes --> (Visible by default, hidden in cooking page)
  |_Videos  --> (Visible by default, hidden in cooking page)
  |_Submit  --> (Visible by default, hidden in cooking page)
Recipes     --> (Hidden by default, set to display block in cooking page)
Videos      --> (Hidden by default, set to display block in cooking page)
Submit      --> (Hidden by default, set to display block in cooking page)
Shop        --> Normal
```

---

Another approach could be **with blocks:** You could have 2 menus, the one in your first image:

```
Home        
Find store  
Cooking     
  |_Recipes 
  |_Videos  
  |_Submit  
Shop
```

And another one like the one in your second image:

```
Home        
Find store  
Recipes 
Videos  
Submit  
Shop
```

And then, through both blocks configuration, you can make the first one visible everywhere **except** in cooking page (e.g. *.../cooking*), and the second one visible **only** in cooking page.

Good luck